# Formula not working where the row reference is stored in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a formula where the sheet name and column always stay the same, but the row changes based on the row number I have stored in a cell:

```
='Sector info'!(CONCAT("C", B2))
```

In the formula above:

1. Sheet name: **`Sector info`**
2. Column: **`C`**
3. Cell holding the row number: **`B2`**

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `&` operator to concatenate text strings, like this:

```
="'Sector info'!C" & B2
```

The result is a text string that *looks like* a cell reference. To retrieve the value in the cell, use [indirect()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093377):

```
=indirect("'Sector info'!C" & B2)
```

That works, but there are other ways to do the same that are usually preferable, such as [chooserows()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13196659):

```
=chooserows('Sector info'!C1:C, B2)
```

...or [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197):

```
=filter('Sector info'!C1:C, row('Sector info'!C1:C) = B2)
```

The latter two formulas will adjust automatically when you insert or delete columns in `'Sector info'`, while the `indirect()` will not.